# DWARF - How to find the prologue end/epilogue start addresses of functions in a given binary?

Tags: c, assembly, objdump, dwarf, readelf

I have an ARM binary of which I need to find exactly at which addresses its function's prologues end and the epilogues begin. In other words, I need the boundaries of the function bodies. For instance, if I have a function whose assembly is something like:

```
0x00000320 <+0>:    push    {r7, lr}
0x00000322 <+2>:    sub sp, #16
0x00000324 <+4>:    add r7, sp, #0
0x00000326 <+6>:    str r0, [r7, #4]
0x00000328 <+8>: (Function body starts here)
...
0x0000034c <+44>:   (Function body ends here)
0x0000034e <+46>:   mov sp, r7
0x00000350 <+48>:   pop {r7, pc}
```

I need a way to quickly find either `0x00000326` and `0x0000034e` (prologue end/epilogue start) or `0x00000328` and `0x0000034c` (function body start/end) using something like readelf or objdump. Simply disassembling it and inspecting the code won't do (ideally I'd be using a script to parse the output of readelf or whatever program I'm using to get the DWARF info).

According to the DWARF 4 standard, the .debug_line section supposedly has line number info which includes "`prologue_end`" and "`epilogue_begin`", which is exactly what I need. However, the output of `arm-linux-readelf --debug-dump=rawline,decodedline` doesn't give me that info.

I'm compiling using `gcc 4.8.2` with the `-ggdb3` flag.

EDIT: Some more info: both objdump and readelf show me something like this:

```
Line Number Statements:
[0x00000074]  Extended opcode 2: set Address to 0x100
[0x0000007b]  Advance Line by 302 to 303
[0x0000007e]  Copy
[0x0000007f]  Special opcode 34: advance Address by 4 to 0x104 and Line by 1 to 304
[0x00000080]  Special opcode 34: advance Address by 4 to 0x108 and Line by 1 to 305
[0x00000081]  Special opcode 37: advance Address by 4 to 0x10c and Line by 4 to 309
[0x00000082]  Special opcode 34: advance Address by 4 to 0x110 and Line by 1 to 310
[0x00000083]  Special opcode 20: advance Address by 2 to 0x112 and Line by 1 to 311
[0x00000084]  Special opcode 37: advance Address by 4 to 0x116 and Line by 4 to 315
[0x00000085]  Special opcode 34: advance Address by 4 to 0x11a and Line by 1 to 316
[0x00000086]  Advance Line by -13 to 303
[0x00000088]  Special opcode 19: advance Address by 2 to 0x11c and Line by 0 to 303
[0x00000089]  Special opcode 34: advance Address by 4 to 0x120 and Line by 1 to 304
[0x0000008a]  Advance PC by 4 to 0x124
[0x0000008c]  Extended opcode 1: End of Sequence
```

Looking at the source of binutils' dwarf.c, it seems that it should be printing something like "Set prologue_end to true" and "Set epilogue_begin to true" in the line info dump. However, all of the opcodes seem to be special instead of standard.

Comment: For what it's worth compiling with "clang-3.6 -gdwarf-4 -g3", I get "Set prologue_end to true" DWARF info: GCC does not seem to be able to generate this (yet?).

Answer (score 2):

This is an extremely belated response, but: **if** you're using LLVM, then you can get this information from the DWARF line program state machine: LLVM emits `DW_LNS_set_prologue_end` and `DW_LNS_set_epilogue_begin` as flags for each line program entry.

GCC apparently doesn't (yet) support these attributes, so its likely that its surrounding tooling (like `readelf` and `gdb`) don't either. But you should be able to parse the prologues and epilogues out with [`pyelftools`](https://github.com/eliben/pyelftools).

Answer (score 1):

If you run dwarfdump on an llvm generated executable you'll see things like this:

```
.debug_line contents:

Address            Line   Column File   ISA Discriminator Flags
------------------ ------ ------ ------ --- ------------- -------------
0x000000010000d0d0     17      0     19   0             0  is_stmt
0x000000010000d0e0     17      1     19   0             0  is_stmt prologue_end
```

What this means is "file 19 on line 17 declares a method, method prologue ends at 0x000000010000d0e0" which I think is supposed to mean "if you want to make a breakpoint for beginning of that method, that's the best place" [guess you have to cross link the file:line:column back to the Dwarf other sections to know which method that actually is?]

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
readelf -wi
```

And look for DW_AT_low_pc and DW_AT_high_pc for the subroutine you are looking at.

The DWARF spec says:

> A subroutine entry may have either a DW_AT_low_pc and DW_AT_high_pc pair of attributes or a DW_AT_ranges attribute whose values encode the contiguous or non-contiguous address ranges, respectively, of the machine instructions generated for the subroutine (see Section 2.17).

If I remember correctly, the DW_AT_low_pc is the address immediately after the prologue and DW_AT_high_pc is the last address before the epilogue.

Don't worry about the opcodes being 'special' that just means that they don't take arguments to save space in the encoded line number program.

Comment: Unfortunately, DW_AT_low_pc seems to correspond to the address of the first instruction of the subroutine (that is, the first prologue instruction) and DW_AT_high_pc seems to be the offset of the instruction that follows the last epilogue instruction.